# Need a declaration of pointer to hold the address of an array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers, linux-kernel

To understand more precisely, see the below explanation.

```
int arr[3];
```

Now, write a declaration in such a way, `xyz = &arr;` where compiler should not throw warning.

How to declare `xyz`?

For the below code,

```
int main(void)
{

int arr[3];
int *p;
int **pp;

p = arr;
pp = &arr;

return 0;
}
```

.

```
WARNING:
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:11:4: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     pp = &arr;
    ^
```

Goal: Need a declaration such that `xyz = &arr`, where it should not throw warning.

Comment: *Why* do you need a pointer to the *array* instead of to its first element (which is the most common use-case by at least 99%)?

Comment: It is a question from interviewer.

Answer (score 3):

`int (*xyz)[3]`

Pointer to an array of 3 `int` elements.

And FYI `int**` and `int (*)[3]` is not same.

Comment: What about `void *xyz = &arr;`?

Comment: @RingØ.: That works..but this needs to be casted ot assigned at some point. And then ...